# Translating Javascript to C# Issues

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, voxel

I've been attempting to convert this [Javascript code](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/mikolalysenko.github.com/blob/master/Isosurface/js/surfacenets.js) into a [C# (Unity3d) script](http://pastebin.com/v2MUYZig). It is an implementation of Naive Surface Nets [explained here](https://0fps.net/2012/07/12/smooth-voxel-terrain-part-2/) if that helps.

My translated C# script does compile without errors/warnings but the result is a broken (but recognizable) mesh:
[image: C# Script in Unity3D]

I've also noticed that the vertices look reasonably correct:
[image]

(If you can't already tell, the input voxels are just simplex noise.)

I'd really like to get this working, but I am not well versed with Javascript.
**Can someone who knows both languages well tell me what I've missed? Thank you.**

EDIT: [Here's the project.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysnemjhs6iemqs0/Unity%20Project.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I'd be happy to help, but I'm unsure of how to receive your project through Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jace I'll Dropbox it and send you a link. Does that work for you?

Comment: Sure, that will do

Comment: @Jace https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysnemjhs6iemqs0/Unity%20Project.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look

Comment: This project requires a concrete understanding of graphics programing, which is an area in which I am not yet proficient. What's interesting to me about this code is that it generates random output with each execution. If it were more predictable, I might be able to pinpoint the problem through process of elimination, but as it is I can't tell whether any one change to the algorithm is getting me closer or further to a solution. I'm sorry I couldn't be of help, this is just way outside my area of expertise.

Comment: @Jace thanks anyways! (also - side note - the code only generates a different mesh when pressing enter, which randomizes the voxels. Running the surface nets script should produce the same mesh as long as the voxels don't change.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I simply mistranslated line 87 of the Javascript code.

Original:

```
for(x[2]=0; x[2]<dims[2]-1; ++x[2], n+=dims[0], buf_no ^= 1, R[2]=-R[2]) {
```

My incorrect translation:

```
for (pos[2] = 0; pos[2] < depth - 1; pos[2]++, bufferNumber ^= 1, R[2] = -R[2] )
```

Corrected to:

```
for (pos[2] = 0; pos[2] < depth - 1; n += width, bufferNumber ^= 1, R[2] = -R[2] )
```

Basically a typo. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Unity's mesh receive a triangle list.
However, Javascript code seems to use quadrilateral list.
You should split a square into two triangles.

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(mask & 1))
{

    faces.Add(buffer[m]);
    faces.Add(buffer[m - dv]);
    faces.Add(buffer[m - du]);

    faces.Add(buffer[m - dv]);
    faces.Add(buffer[m - du - dv]);
    faces.Add(buffer[m - du]);
}
else
{
    faces.Add(buffer[m]);
    faces.Add(buffer[m - du]);
    faces.Add(buffer[m - dv]);

    faces.Add(buffer[m - du]);
    faces.Add(buffer[m - du - dv]);
    faces.Add(buffer[m - dv]);
}

mesh.SetTriangles(faces, 0);
```

and your three dimensional array implement has something wrong...
original Javascript code with single array works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I've already solved it! I just forgot to post it here. It was a very small translation error on my part. And yes, I know Unity prefers triangles, and I've already implemented your solution before even knowing you had posted it here. (Beforehand I was using `Mesh.SetIndices()` which allows you to specify quads instead of triangles) None of this matters now, though. This meshing method has some fundamental issues when used with voxel data in chunks. I'm going to scrap this method and try another method like marching cubes or dual contouring.